# Using jsoup to get contents of a table

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Am trying to use jsoup to grap the contents of a URL (table:- contents) into an arraylist. So far, have hit dead ends when searching online for questions similar to mine. Maybe a fresh eyes will help. This is what I have so far which is not much.I read somewhere that I need to identify the table id then work using Elements to loop through the  tag for each row, if true how?

```
try {               
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.us-proxy.org").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36").get();
    //utilize the fetched html    
} catch(Exception e{  
    e.printStackTrace();   
}
```

Here is my output source of the URL  html site(relevant part) :-

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display fpltable" id="proxylisttable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>IP Address</th>
      <th>Port</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Anonymity</th>
      <th>Google</th>
      <th>Https</th>
      <th>Last Checked</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>24.210.34.226</td><td>3128</td><td>US</td><td>United States</td><td>transparent</td><td>no</td><td>no</td><td>18 hours 20 minutes ago</td></tr>
    <tr><td>50.76.49.97</td><td>4444</td><td>US</td><td>United States</td><td>transparent</td><td>no</td><td>no</td><td>18 hours 20 minutes ago</td></tr>
    <tr><td>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th class="input"><input type="text" /></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

My desired output should look something like this proxy : 50.76.49.97 port:4444 country: United States type: Transparent .....

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Elements elements = doc.select("table[class=display fpltable]");

    Elements rows = elements.get(0).select("tr");

    for (Element row : rows) {

        if (row.select("td").size() == 8) {
            String iPAddress = row.select("td").get(0).text();
            String port = row.select("td").get(1).text();
            String code = row.select("td").get(2).text();
            String country = row.select("td").get(3).text();
            String anonymity = row.select("td").get(4).text();
            String google = row.select("td").get(5).text();
            String https = row.select("td").get(6).text();
            String lastChecked = row.select("td").get(7).text();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Tnk for the answer just one question in your code, Is it possible to query the for table class name without hardcoding the name? As the site may change such in the future. I mean this "table[class=display fpltable]")

Comment: If only one table you can use without this param  "class=display fpltable".

as following: Elements elements = doc.select("table");